# jQuery filter with live refresh page

Tags: jquery

I am trying to create a filter to hide/show divs but the problem is that the page also refreshes live to get data so whenever I search, it hides the items that it should hide but everything comes back in the end because of the page refresh, what could I do to fix that? I would also appreciate code examples since I don't have that much experience with jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#feed').load('load-feed.php', function () {

    });
    setInterval(function () {
        search = $('#search').val();
        $('#feed').load('load-feed.php', function () {

        });
    }, 1000);

    $("#search").on('input', function () {
        var matcher = new RegExp($(this).val(), 'gi');
        $('.feed-event').show().not(function () {
            return matcher.test($(this).find('.club-text').text())
        }).hide();
    });
});
```

Comment: You can use localStorage.setItem("toggleStatus", closed); and localStorage.getItem("toggleStatus"); and get the value on page load and show / hide accordingly.

Comment: How do you want it to work? If you keep refreshing the items every second, how do you intend to filter them? Maybe you should pause the interval if user types something in the search-box?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you are using php. What you could do is;

1) Make a separate file that echoes data only; let's say in **search_feed.php** you have a SQL query then convert it to a string then echo it.

2) Make use of **ajax** to avoid constantly loading your file to your web page. With ajax, you can request for data and modify html elements asynchronously.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/ajax_get.asp

```
$("#search").keyup(function(){
    var search = $(this).val();

    $.get("search_feed.php?filter="+search, function(data, status){

        // loop through result data
        $(data).each(function(i,v){
          // modify html table or other elements here
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: Thank you, will look into this